# Appending line to file using OneDrive SDK c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

I'd like to append a line to a file that's on my OneDrive using the OneDrive SDK.  Am I right in saying that the only way to do so is to download the entire file, append the line and then re-upload?  Or is there a way I can get a writeable stream to the file?

Nick.

Comment: Try use FileIo.App* to add the line and update to oneDrive

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that, not had much time this week.

Comment: Did the problem solve?